# how to save whitespaces while parsing array to string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Let's say during some string operations we have this kind of array:

`[0] = "Foo"
[1] = "   " (3 spaces)
[2] = "bar"
[3] = "  " (2 spaces)`

we separated incoming string with regex using word break (/\b/g), and we wanna save all source spaces in output

doing 
    `str.join(" ")`
will erase all elements with spaces resulting in "Foo bar", instead we want to get "Foo   bar  " string. I guess this is because of converting arr[1] that is "    " (3 spaces) to String.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `['Foo', '   ', 'bar'].join(' ') === "Foo     bar"`(er, there are supposed to be 5 spaces there, [markdown problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296038/multiple-spaces-in-code-markdown-arent-properly-rendered))

Comment: sorry for confusing , guys and thx for answering. it actually all works great. My problem with that part of code along with posting non-reproduceable example was in simple css-ruling that trails white-spaces :
its - white-spaces: pre ( and problem gone ).

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = ["Foo", "   ", "bar", "  "];

var str = arr.join(" ");

console.log('"' + str + '"');
console.log("str length: " + str.length);
```

Works here... although you probably really meant to do `arr.join("");` without the space.

Comment: "Your code works as expected" -> VTC as non-reproducible (off-topic reason) instead of answering